# Job queue where workers can add jobs, is there an elegant solution to stop the program when all workers are idle?

Tags: go, concurrency

I find myself in a situation where I have a queue of jobs where workers can add new jobs when they are done processing one.

For illustration, in the code below, a job consists in counting up to `JOB_COUNTING_TO` and, randomly, 1/5 of the time a worker will add a new job to the queue.

Because my workers can add jobs to the queue, it is my understanding that I was not able to use a channel as my job queue. This is because sending to the channel is blocking and, even with a buffered channel, this code, due to its recursive nature (jobs adding jobs) could easily reach a situation where all the workers are sending to the channel and no worker is available to receive.

This is why I decided to use a shared queue protected by a mutex.

Now, I would like the program to halt when all the workers are idle. Unfortunately this cannot be spotted just by looking for when `len(jobQueue) == 0` as the queue could be empty but some worker still doing their job and maybe adding a new job after that.

The solution I came up with is, I feel a bit clunky, it makes use of variables `var idleWorkerCount int` and  `var isIdle [NB_WORKERS]bool` to keep track of idle workers and the code stops when `idleWorkerCount == NB_WORKERS`.

My question is if there is a concurrency pattern that I could use to make this logic more elegant?

Also, for some reason I don't understand the technique that I currently use (code below) becomes really inefficient when the number of Workers becomes quite big (such as 300000 workers): for the same number of jobs, the code will be > 10x slower for `NB_WORKERS = 300000` vs `NB_WORKERS = 3000`.

Thank you very much in advance!

```golang
package main

import (
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
)

const NB_WORKERS = 3000
const NB_INITIAL_JOBS = 300
const JOB_COUNTING_TO = 10000000

var jobQueue []int
var mu sync.Mutex
var idleWorkerCount int
var isIdle [NB_WORKERS]bool

func doJob(workerId int) {

    mu.Lock()

    if len(jobQueue) == 0 {
        if !isIdle[workerId] {
            idleWorkerCount += 1
        }
        isIdle[workerId] = true
        mu.Unlock()
        return
    }

    if isIdle[workerId] {
        idleWorkerCount -= 1
    }
    isIdle[workerId] = false

    var job int
    job, jobQueue = jobQueue[0], jobQueue[1:]
    mu.Unlock()

    for i := 0; i < job; i += 1 {
    }

    if rand.Intn(5) == 0 {
        mu.Lock()
        jobQueue = append(jobQueue, JOB_COUNTING_TO)
        mu.Unlock()
    }

}

func main() {

    // Filling up the queue with initial jobs
    for i := 0; i < NB_INITIAL_JOBS; i += 1 {
        jobQueue = append(jobQueue, JOB_COUNTING_TO)
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < NB_WORKERS; i += 1 {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(workerId int) {
            for idleWorkerCount != NB_WORKERS {
                doJob(workerId)
            }
            wg.Done()
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why spawning a new goroutine for each new job and using a semaphore (if needed) to control the number of jobs executing at once is not a good option? This would allow to trivially wait for all goroutines to complete (at which point the "queue" is implicitly empty). Are you worried about memory usage? If so you should include this as an explicit requirement.
You should also probably explain why you need such a high number of workers. What do the workers do exactly?

Comment: *This is why I decided to use a shared queue protected by a mutex* — A channel **is** a queue protected by a mutex

Comment: @blackgreen I did not know thank you! The issue I had with channels, as explained in the post, is that sending to a channel is blocking and this algorithm can yield deadlocks.

Comment: @CAFxX My first implementation was exactly what you propose: recursively calling "go doJob" without protecting it with a semaphore. That worked well at first but because the job to do is some kind of exponential mathematical process, very quickly the number of goroutines became prohibitive (> 500 000) and program crashed. I tried to protect it with a buffered `chan struct{}` but that ran into deadlocks that I did not understand.

Comment: @CAFxX: here is a code corresponding to what I think you propose https://pastebin.com/mXB76Ft9 it deadlocks for a reason I do not understand

Answer (score 1):

> Because my workers can add jobs to the queue

A re entrant channel always deadlock. This is easy to demonstrate using this code

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    out := make(chan string)
    c := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        for v := range c {
            c <- v + " 2"
            out <- v
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        c <- "hello world!" // pass OK
        c <- "hello world!" // no pass, the routine is blocking at pushing to itself
    }()

    for v := range out {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }

}
```

While the program

- tries to push at `c <- v + " 2"`

it can not

- read at `for v := range c {`,
- push at `c <- "hello world!"`
- read at `for v := range out {`

thus, it deadlocks.

If you want to pass that situation you must overflow somewhere.

On the routines, or somewhere else.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    out := make(chan string)
    c := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        for v := range c {
            go func() { // use routines on the stack as a bank for the required overflow.
                <-time.After(time.Second) // simulate slowliness.
                c <- v + " 2"
            }()
            out <- v
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for {
            c <- "hello world!"
        }
    }()

    exit := time.After(time.Second * 60)
    for v := range out {
        fmt.Println(v)
        select {
        case <-exit:
            return
        default:
        }
    }
}
```

But now you have a new problem.

You created a memory bomb by overflowing without limits on the stack. Technically, this is dependent on the time needed to finish a job, the memory available, the speed of your cpus and the shape of the data (they might or might not generate a new job). So there is a upper limit, but it is so hard to make sense of it, that in practice this ends up to be a bomb.

Consider not overflowing without limits on the stack.

If you dont have any arbitrary limit on hand, you can use a semaphore to cap the overflow.

https://play.golang.org/p/5JWPQiqOYKz

my bombs did not explode with a work timeout of 1s and 2s, but they took a large chunk of memory.

[image: my bombs did not explode with a work timeout of 1s and 2s]

In another round with a modified code, it exploded

[image]

Of course, because you use `if rand.Intn(5) == 0 {` in your code, the problem is largely mitigated. Though, when you meet such pattern, think twice to the code.

> Also, for some reason I don't understand the technique that I currently use (code below) becomes really inefficient when the number of Workers becomes quite big (such as 300000 workers): for the same number of jobs, the code will be > 10x slower for NB_WORKERS = 300000 vs NB_WORKERS = 3000.

In the big picture, you have a limited amount of cpu cycles. All those allocations and instructions, to spawn and synchronize, has to be executed too. Concurrency is not free.

> Now, I would like the program to halt when all the workers are idle.

I came up with that but i find it very difficult to reason about and convince myself it wont end up in a `write on closed channel` panic.

The idea is to use a [sync.WaitGroup](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup) to count in flight items and rely on it to properly close the input channel and finish the job.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var wgr sync.WaitGroup
    out := make(chan string)
    c := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        for v := range c {
            if rand.Intn(5) == 0 {
                wgr.Add(1)
                go func(v string) {
                    <-time.After(time.Microsecond)
                    c <- v + " 2"
                }(v)
            }
            wgr.Done()
            out <- v
        }
        close(out)
    }()

    var sent int
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 300; i++ {
            wgr.Add(1)
            c <- "hello world!"
            sent++
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        wgr.Wait()
        close(c)
    }()

    var rcv int
    for v := range out {
        // fmt.Println(v)
        _ = v
        rcv++
    }
    log.Println("sent", sent)
    log.Println("rcv", rcv)
}
```

I ran it with `while go run -race .; do :; done` it worked fine for a reasonable amount of iterations.

Comment: Sorry for the late late reply! Thank you so much for your very thorough analysis. I managed to get over my problem by batching more than 1 job per go-routine. Thank you!